# Calculate integral recurrence formula

Tags: integration, recurrence-relations, indefinite-integrals

I'm trying to calculate recurrence formula for the following integral:

$$I=
\int{\frac{1}{{\sin}^n(x)}dx}$$

While I have some ideas for even sinus degrees, have nothing to do for $n$ being odd.

Comment: What have you tried? Have you already calculated the integral for the first few values of n?

Comment: Yeah, using integration by parts, however it seems pretty useless..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$$I_n=\int{\frac{1}{{\sin}^n x}dx}=\int \csc^n x dx = -\int \csc^{n-2} d(\cot x) 
$$

Integrate by parts,

$$I_n=-\csc^{n-2}\cot x -(n-2)\int \csc^{n-2} \cot^2 x dx $$
$$=-\csc^{n-2}\cot x -(n-2)\int \csc^{n-2} (\csc^2 x -1)dx $$
$$=-\csc^{n-2}\cot x -(n-2)I_n + (n-2)I_{n-2} $$

Thus, the  recurrence formula is

$$I_n = -\frac1{n-1}\csc^{n-2}\cot x + \frac{n-2}{n-1}I_{n-2}$$

Comment: Got it, great idea.